# This Query is Not Working

Tags: php

```
$qurym="SELECT * FROM referal_member WHERE `ref_cusid` = '$id' && `confirm` = '1'";
$resm=mysqli_query($con,$qurym);
$rowm=mysqli_fetch_array($resm);
```

Comment: so what error you get? what not working?

Comment: Have you got any error???

Comment: `ref_cusid` = '$id' and `confirm` this all so not working bro

Comment: @Uchiha `&&` is correct syntax https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html

Comment: sry bro mistake is me thanks for ur help

Comment: not it properly working bro thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just try like this: [ if fields ( `ref_cusid` and `confirm`) are of `INT` type, then pass values `$id` and `1` without single quotes ( `'` ), otherwise make change as below ]

```
$qurym = "SELECT * FROM referal_member 
          WHERE `ref_cusid` = ' " . $id . "' 
          AND `confirm` = '1'";

$resm = mysqli_query($con,$qurym);
// check query returns something or not
if(mysqli_num_rows($resm)){
 // fetch data 
  $rowm=mysqli_fetch_array($resm);
}
else{
 // no data found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove quotes from confirm if it is integer datatype.

```
$qurym="SELECT * FROM referal_member WHERE `ref_cusid` = '$id' && `confirm` = 1";
$resm=mysqli_query($con,$qurym);
$rowm=mysqli_fetch_array($resm);
print_r($rowm); // to check results.
```

Or If ref_cusid is also integer type.

```
$qurym="SELECT * FROM referal_member WHERE `ref_cusid` = $id && `confirm` = 1";
$resm=mysqli_query($con,$qurym);
$rowm=mysqli_fetch_array($resm);
print_r($rowm); // to check results.
```

Comment: second value like confirm = 1 its only not working bro

Comment: @shiyamSundar - could u plz tell me error you getting and also ref_cusid is integer or string type ??